# Jax-rsで作ったREST APIを呼ぼうとURLを入力すると404 Not Foundエラーになってしまう

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs

Jax-rsを使って、簡単なREST APIを作成しようとしています。
GETメソッドで2つの数字を受け取り、その和をプレーンテキストで返すREST APIです。
以下のページを参考にしています。
https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/1411/10/news105.html

上記ページに合わせるため、Java、Tomcat、Jerseyのバージョンは少し古いものを使用しています。
Java 1.8.0
Tomcat 8
Jersey 2.25.0

Javaのソースコード

```
package com.example;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("add")
public class Add {
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String add(@QueryParam("x") String ax, @QueryParam("y") String ay) {
    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(ax);
    BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(ay);
    return x.add(y).toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Add a = new Add();
    System.out.println(a.add(args[0], args[1]));
  }
}
```

以下のコマンドラインでビルドしています

```
javac -cp %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\calc\WEB-INF\lib\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar Add.java
```

※上記lib配下にJerseyの.jarをすべて配置しています。

web.xmlの内容

```
<web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Tomcatはポート番号などを変更しておらずデフォルトのまま(8080)使用しています。

Tomcatの起動ログを見る限り、コンテクストcalcは正しく起動できているように見えます。（以下一部抜粋。その他の行にもエラーなし）
07-May-2022 01:19:42.256 情報 [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory ディレクトリ [C:\pleiades\2022-03\tomcat\8\webapps\calc] の Web アプリケーションの配備は [1,094] ms で完了しました。

Webアプリケーションの構成は以下の通りです。

```
[CATALINA_HOME]
└[webapps]
　└[calc]
　　└[WEB-INF]
　　　　├[classes]
　　　　｜　└[com]
　　　　｜　　└[example]
　　　　｜　　　└Add.class
　　　　├[lib]
　　　　｜　├javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
　　　　｜　└その他Jerseyのjarファイルすべて
　　　　└web.xml
```

treeコマンドを使ったフォルダ階層は以下の通りです。

```
C:\pleiades\2022-03\tomcat\8\webapps>tree /f calc
フォルダー パスの一覧:  ボリューム OS
ボリューム シリアル番号は 00000031 64E6:0238 です
C:\PLEIADES\2022-03\TOMCAT\8\WEBAPPS\CALC
└─WEB-INF
    │  web.xml
    │
    ├─classes
    │  └─com
    │      └─example
    │              Add.class
    │
    └─lib
            aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar
            hk2-api-2.5.0-b32.jar
            hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar
            hk2-utils-2.5.0-b32.jar
            javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
            javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
            javax.inject-2.5.0-b32.jar
            javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
            javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
            jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar
            jersey-client.jar
            jersey-common.jar
            jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
            jersey-container-servlet.jar
            jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar
```

この状態で以下のURLにアクセスすると404エラーが発生します。
http://127.0.0.1:8080/calc/add?x=100000000&y=80000000000

Tomcatのログには404以外には特にエラーは出ていない状況です。

なぜ404になってしまうのか、原因がわかる方ご教示お願いいたします。

Comment: 質問文中のコードを利用して実行してみましたが、特に問題なく結果は出力されました。とすると、 `web.xml`, `Add.class` のうち、少なくとも一方の置き場所が本来と異なることが考えられます。[`tree` コマンド](https://qiita.com/Qsugi/items/aebd6e790a5928eb84fc) でディレクトリ構成を正確に出力してみてもらえないでしょうか。

Comment: わざわざ実施していただきありがとうございます。treeコマンドの結果を追加で記載しました。見る限り自分が認識している範囲では間違いはなさそうでした…。